# Angular route Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am trying to use angular routing. It is however throwing the error 
*Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error*

When i load pages nothing happens, where I want it to load the content from the corresponding HTML files.

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="nepharia">
<head>
    <title>Nepharia</title>
    <meta charset='utf8' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.min.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans:300italic,300,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="TopMenu">
        <ul>

            <li class="logo"><a href="/">CinemaDesign</a></li>

            <li ng-class="getClass('/latest')"><a href="/latest">Latest movies</a></li>

            <li ng-class="getClass('/upcoming')"><a href="/upcoming">Upcoming movies</a></li>

            <li ng-class="getClass('/order')"><a href="/order">Your order</a></li>

            <li><a href="/info">Info</a></li>

            <li class="login right"><a href="/login"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>

            <li class="search"><a href="/search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main ng-cloak ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="light"></main>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var nepharia = angular.module('nepharia', ['ngRoute']);

    nepharia.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider, $location) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/v/typography.html',
            controller  : 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/latest', {
            templateUrl : '/v/latest.html',
            controller  : 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/upcoming', {
            templateUrl : '/v/upcoming.html',
            controller  : 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/order', {
            templateUrl : '/v/order.html',
            controller  : 'mainCtrl'
        }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });


    nepharia.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.getClass = function (path) {
            if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) == path) {
                return "active"
            } else {
                return ""
            }
        }
    });
```

If it helps, you can see the site I am playing with at [nepharia.net](http://nepharia.net)

Thanks in advance!

[Error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=nepharia&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524location%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:6:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:38:7%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:36:13)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:36:283)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:34:498)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:35:117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:34:399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ab%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:38:135)

Comment: Post the full error stack please - link and all.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the error link it produces.

Comment: as a couple people have stated, you are incorrectly injecting `$location` into your `.config` function.  However, I would also like to suggest, when you are trying to debug errors with Angular, it's really much easier to interpret the errors if you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line in your script:

```
nepharia.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider, $location) {
```

To

```
nepharia.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
```

Should help.

And here are some more details about why:

$location is a service : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

> The $location **service** parses the URL in the browser address bar (based
>   on the window.location) and makes the URL available to your
>   application. Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into
>   $location **service** and changes to $location are reflected into the
>   browser address bar.

And in the angular docs you will see the following (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module , at "Module Loading & Dependencies"):

> A module is a collection of configuration and run blocks which get
>   applied to the application during the bootstrap process. In its
>   simplest form the module consist of a collection of two kinds of
>   blocks:
>
> 1. **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations
>      and configuration phase. **Only providers and constants can be injected**
>      into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>      of services before they have been fully configured.
> 2. **Run blocks** - get
>      executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the
>      application. **Only instances and constants can be injected** into run
>      blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during
>      application run time.

Information about Providers -> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers (Bulletpoint: "Provider Recipe")

Hope this helps to understand the point with $location.

Answer (score 1):

The $location service cannot be injected to the config section, as only providers and constants are allowed. You can use it in the run section, but anyway I don't see you are using it, excpet for you controller, which you should inject it into:

```
nepharia.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.getClass = function (path) {
        if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) == path) {
            return "active"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't really change anything as far as I can see. Sorry I am new to js.. Just playing around trying to make it work lol.

Comment: are your sure your `script.js` is running?

Comment: Running? I've linked to the js file in the html. That's how it usually works. Does Angular require something specific?

Comment: just try to get it running in jsfiddle or jsbin -> would help a lot

Comment: @RubenBlackwood no, but maybe your `base` tag in the html causes the script to not execute